# What is the correct way to write native method signatures in Android NDK using Android Studio?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a working implementation of NDK library and corresponding Java-class. But I get error with ndk method...
i used Android studio 1.5
gradle 2.8 experimental:0.4.0

My Code is...

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

jstring Java_com_example_shivlabs_ndktest_MainActivity_HelloWorld(JNIEnv* env,jobject obj)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"HelloWorld");
}
```

above is My ndktest.c file.

i get error when i declare native method..error is Reports native method declarations in Java where no corresponding JNI function is found in the project.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public native String HelloWorld();

    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("ndktest");
    }
}
```

how can solve it????

Comment: The correct way in all cases is to use the output of `javah.` That's what it's for. Don't do things manually that the computer can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your directory structure looks like but your method signature looks correct.

But I think you forgot the following declaration above your method.

`JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL`

So your method should look like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
jstring Java_com_example_shivlabs_ndktest_MainActivity_HelloWorld(JNIEnv* env,jobject obj)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"HelloWorld");
}
```